# What's the use of spread-radius when we can increase the shadow size by the horizontal and vertical offsets?

Tags: css

Regarding the `spread-radius` attribute of the `box-shadow` property, the MDN docs [say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow):

> Positive values will cause the shadow to expand and grow bigger,
> negative values will cause the shadow to shrink

but the shadow size is already defined by the first two parameters of the `shadow-box` property - the horizontal and vertical `offset`. Then what's the use of this property?

Comment: The offset define the position not the blur size.

Comment: a circle can have a (1) radius (2) positon if its center [x y] <--- you add to this a blur factor and you got 4 variables

Comment: If you were in a zombie apocalypse, the spread radius will define the splatter bonus.

Comment: @TemaniAfif x and y offsets increase the shadow size. The spread-radius also increases the shadow size. I'm unable to understand the difference.

Comment: x,y control the position not the size

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, without affecting how blurry the shadow is, the spread of the shadow essentially grows and shrinks the surface area occupied by the shadow. If you thought of it as the size of the shadow, you wouldn’t be too far off.

If you leave off either the blur or spread radius, their values will default to zero. Looking around the web, you’re likely to see that most demos that you come across, including those on Design Shack, have no spread radius defined.
[image]

Comment: Right, spread-radius is sort of like the size of shadow, but the x and y offset also define the size of shadow no? If you increase the x and y offsets, the shadow size will also increase. The, what's the use of spread-radius when the same thing can be achieved by the offsets?